# Select/unselect list items using checkbox or button

Tags: desktop-application, checkboxes, multi-selection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check all / uncheck all checkboxes with regards to usability](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/check-all-uncheck-all-checkboxes-with-regards-to-usability)

For a couple of applications one can find a checkbox to select/unselect all items in a list. As soon as you click it, all the items in the list will be selected or unselected. IMHO thats wrong, because the checkbox should indicate a state and no action. What's your opinion about it?

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right. clicking a checkbox must not carry out an action immediately. 
In this case a button must be used.