# ux review word for select all

Tags: controls, labels, checkboxes, multi-selection, wording

[image]

Is is ok to use Select/Deselect All here or better to shorten it to only select all.
Would the users know that if they uncheck the "select all" checkbox. Everything will be disselected

Comment: I don't know whether or not *every* user would intuitively know that clearing a "Select All" check box would clear all the subsidiary check boxes, but a few seconds of using the UI will show them that it does.

Comment: related http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/check-all-uncheck-all-checkboxes-with-regards-to-usability

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are 2 possible confusions here:

1. Putting two opposite labels (calls-to-action) on the same controller.
2. Using a check-box controller for manipulating the UI rather then selecting multiple items, which is their intended purpose.

What I would do is make it a button (or a link if there's a more important button nearby). The button label (or link) should only be the available action: "Select All" if not all items are selected, and "Deselect All" otherwise.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRjCgk.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Edit: after showing this answer to a co-league, I want to point out that if there are a lot of check-boxes, it's worth having both buttons/links available (it can be exhausting to deselect dozens of check-boxes manually).

Comment: I do like the idea of using a button rather than a checkbox for the (de)select all feature, however it can also work very nicely to use a checkbox. One idea, would be to simply help the user "visually identify" this special checkbox via styling (ie. a border surrounding the checkbox & its label), see how google mail does it http://i.imgur.com/DNBhp8x.png

Comment: Another note: your idea (a button vs a checkbox) to change a group of checkboxes states is used by `modernizr` - but to toggle (inverts states) checkbox rather than to (de)select all. see http://i.imgur.com/Yzhxsbf.png or directly on http://modernizr.com/download/