# Research behind select all/none

Tags: usability, selection, multi-selection, deselection

There are [a variety of ways](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/check-all-uncheck-all-checkboxes-with-regards-to-usability) to implement selecting everything or nothing in a list.

Is there any usability research comparing the different approaches?

Comment: By reflex I visited nngroup.com which, surprisingly, has nothing.

Answer (score -4):

Select all - Used when a user needs to perform bulk operations on all the items from list/table.

Select none - to unselect selected options or undo select all

Comment: I was asking about research on the different approaches, not what they mean